# TextView as data type

Tags: android, android-activity, types, textview

I am newbie in android apps development. I code this:

```
public void onClickedButton(){
    TextView theText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);   
}
```

but the error icon said: TextView cannot be resolved to a data Type. Why?

and I look at the android documentation, it is the public class of "VIEW". What does it mean?

Can anyone help and explain me? thanks!

Comment: Have you added the `import`?

Comment: First, have you imported the class? Is TextView red? If so hover the mouse over or press ctrl + enter. See what it says. Second, I'd try cleaning the project as that sounds a bit funny.
Lastly ensure your corresponding xml has a a *TextView* element with an id of android:id="@+id/mytext".

Comment: Check your id of TextView in XML Layout. Also try adding import android.R in your header.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a little bug of eclipse.
Just erase the name of your textView ("mytext"), save your changes and then type it again and save.

The error will disappear.